# show some variables not whole

Tags: android, android-listview

I get some variables with json from text(such as  name, city, school etc..) and I have 2 files  list_view.xml and singlelistview.xml first I want to show some variables in listview then when the click on and pass to singlelistview I can see all variables

Comment: Please show code and xml files.

Answer (score 0):

implement the next function :

[OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

this will return u the position.
  grab a var and send it to a Fragment which inflater the singlelistview.xml file
  send the var and send it to the fragment and inside the fragment grab the data needed and display it.

```
Adapter mAdapter; //what u fill the ListView with.

onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     String s = mAdapter.getItem(position);
     SingleFragment frag = new SingleFragment();
     Bundle bund = new Bundle();
     bund.putString(KEY_NAME,s)
     frag.setArguments(bund);
     //show fragment



 }
```

Hope it Helps.
    [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)